# How can I get the iphone hardware serial number with the help of the Delphi?

Tags: c#, ios, delphi, itunes

How can I get the iphone hardware serial number with the help of the Delphi?
hardware information:main serial number, battery serial number, camera and screen serial number

Comment: You cannot. Perhaps describe why you wish to; there may be alternatives.

Comment: search on google 3utools idevice verification

Comment: I want to write a program like 3utools idevice verification.

Comment: To identify devices that have changed one of its parts.

Comment: "search on google 3utools idevice verification" Somehow I missed this back in December. I thought your question was about how to do it from an app on the device itself. I know how to do it from an app running on a Mac (by using the MobileDevice framework); I am yet to discover how to do it from a Windows app.

Comment: I want to create a program for detecting mobile replacement parts. How do you get this information on the Mac? Maybe knowing it can help me

Comment: i also want to create a program to detect duplicate parts, So does anyone got the info. i am able to get the current parts serial number but how do i get the base/old part serial number.Does anyone has idea? i checked 3utools i think he is using some Rest API for that. because verification report is not showing while offline.